# Spring - Issue setting dialect in Hibernate JPA Configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm moving from a Spring Boot 1.5.9 to a normal Spring project.

In `application.properties` I've added

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[0]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[1]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[2]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[3]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

In `application.properties` I have a line that defines the dialect I'm using, it worked properly with the autoconfiguration

`spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl`

When I try to run the project with the new configuration class I have `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'`, I have the same error with the autoconfiguration if i remove the dialect line.
My way to specify the properties, including the dialect, in the configuration class is the following

```
private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();

public HibernateJpaConfig() {
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
    properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyComponentPathImpl");
}
```

I noticed a warning message that might be my issue

```
WARN 13292 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000006: Attempted to specify unsupported NamingStrategy via setting [hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy]; NamingStrategy has been removed in favor of the split ImplicitNamingStrategy and PhysicalNamingStrategy; use [hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy] or [hibernate.physical_naming_strategy], respectively, instead.
```

If I try to replace the second value of the map with one of those I still have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at this release note of spring boot. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#naming-strategy

I think problem is in naming_strategy.

SpringNamingStrategy is no longer used as Hibernate 5.1 has removed support for the old NamingStrategy interface. A new SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy is now auto-configured which is used in combination with Hibernate’s default ImplicitNamingStrategy. This should be very close to (if not identical) to Spring Boot 1.3 defaults, however, you should check your Database schema is correct when upgrading.

If you were already using Hibernate 5 before upgrading, you may be using Hibernate’s 5 default. If you want to restore them after the upgrade, set this property in your configuration:

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl